# Prob. 25, Chap. 5 in Baby Rudin: Newton's Method

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, derivatives, numerical-methods, fixed-points

Here is Prob. 25, Chap. 5 in the book *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* by Walter Rudin, 
3rd edition:

> Suppose $f$ is twice differentiable on $[a, b]$, $f(a) < 0$, $f(b) > 0$, $f^\prime(x) \geq \delta > 0$, 
>   and $0 \leq f^{\prime\prime}(x) \leq M$ for all $x \in [a, b]$. Let $\xi$ be the unique point in $[a, b]$
>   at which $f(\xi) = 0$.
>
> Complete the details in the following outline of *Newton's method* for computing $\xi$.
>
> (a) Choose $x_1 \in (\xi, b)$, and define $\left\{ x_n \right\}$ by
>   $$ x_{n+1} = x_n - \frac{ f\left(x_n \right)}{f^\prime\left(x_n\right)}.$$
>   Interpret this geometrically, in terms of a tangent to the graph of $f$.
>
> (b) Prove that $x_{n+1} < x_n$ and that $$ \lim_{n \to \infty} x_n =\xi.$$
>
> (c) Use Taylor's theorem to show that 
>   $$ x_{n+1} - \xi = \frac{ f^{\prime\prime}\left( t_n \right) }{ 2 f^\prime \left( x_n \right) }
> \left( x_n - \xi \right)^2 $$
>   for some $t_n \in \left( \xi, x_n \right)$.
>
> (d) If $A = M / 2\delta$, deduce that 
>   $$ 0 \leq x_{n+1} - \xi \leq \frac{1}{A} \left[ A \left( x_1 - \xi \right) \right]^{2^n}.$$
>   (Compare with Exercises 16 and 18, Chapter 3.)
>
> (e) Show that Newton's method amounts to finding a fixed point of the function $g$ defined by
>   $$ g(x) = x - \frac{ f(x) }{ f^\prime(x) }. $$
>   How does $g^\prime(x)$ behave for $x$ near $\xi$?
>
> (f) Put $f(x) = x^{1/3}$ on $( - \infty, \infty)$ and try Newton's method. What happens?

Solutions:

Part (a);

> The tangent to the graph of $f$ at the point $\left( x_n, f \left( x_n \right) \right)$ has the equation 
>   $$ y = f\left( x_n \right) + f^\prime \left( x_n \right) \left( x - x_n \right). $$
>   Let $x_{n+1}$ be the abscissa of the point at which this line intersects the $x$-axis. Then we have 
>   $$ 0 =  f\left( x_n \right) + f^\prime \left( x_n \right) \left( x_{n+1} - x_n \right). $$
>   Solving the last equation for $x_{n+1}$, we obtain 
>   $$ x_{n+1} = = x_n - \frac{ f\left(x_n \right)}{f^\prime\left(x_n\right)}.$$

Part (b):

> As $f^\prime(x) > 0$, so $f$ is strictly increasing on $[a, b]$, and as $\xi < x_1 < b$, so $f ( \xi) = 0 < f \left( x_1 \right) < f(b)$; thus $f \left( x_1 \right) > 0$, and so 
>   $$x_2 = x_1 - f \left( x_1 \right)/f^\prime \left( x_1 \right) < x_1.$$
>   As $f^{\prime\prime} \geq 0$, so $f^\prime$ is monotonically increasing.
>
> By the mean-value theorem we can find a point $c_1 \in \left( x_2, x_1 \right)$ such that 
>   $$
> \begin{align}
> f\left( x_2 \right) 
> &= f\left( x_1 \right) + f^\prime\left( c_1 \right) \left( x_2 - x_1 \right) \\ 
> &= f\left( x_1 \right) - f^\prime\left( c_1 \right) \left( x_1 - x_2 \right) \\
> & \geq f\left( x_1 \right) - f^\prime\left( x_1 \right) \left( x_1 - x_2 \right) \\
> & \qquad \mbox{[ as $x_2 < c_1 < x_1$ and as $f^\prime$ is monotonically increasing, } \\
> & \qquad \mbox{ so $f^\prime \left( x_2 \right) \leq f^\prime \left( c_1 \right) \leq f^\prime \left(x_1 \right)$.]} \\
> &= f^\prime\left( x_1 \right) \left[ \frac{ f\left( x_1 \right) }{ f^\prime\left( x_1 \right) } - x_1 + x_2 \right] \\
> &= f^\prime\left( x_1 \right) \left( -x_2 + x_2 \right) \\
> &= 0 \\
> &= f \left( \xi \right),
> \end{align}
> $$ 
>   and as $f$ is strictly increasing, so we can conclude that $x_2 \geq \xi$. Now if $x_2 = \xi$, then we see that 
>   $$ x_3 = x_2 - \frac{ f\left(x_2 \right)}{f^\prime\left(x_2\right)} = \xi - \frac{ f\left(\xi  \right)}{f^\prime\left(\xi\right)} = \xi,.$$
>   and hence 
>   $$x_4 = x_3 - \frac{ f\left(x_3 \right)}{f^\prime\left(x_3 \right)} = \xi - \frac{ f\left(\xi  \right)}{f^\prime\left(\xi\right)} = \xi,.$$
>   and so on. Thus $x_n = \xi$ for all $n \geq 2$ and so $x_n \to \xi$ as $n \to \infty$. So we suppose that $x_2 > \xi$.
>
> Now suppose that $x_n$, where $n \geq 2$, has been found so that $\xi < x_n$. Then $0 = f(\xi) < f\left(x_n \right)$, and so 
>   $$x_{n+1} = x_n - \frac{ f\left( x_n \right) }{ f^\prime \left( x_n \right) } <  x_n,$$
>   and there exists a point $c \in \left( x_{n+1}, x_n \right)$ such that 
>   $$
> \begin{align}
> f\left( x_{n+1} \right) 
> &= f\left( x_n \right) + f^\prime\left( c \right) \left( x_{n+1} - x_n \right) \\ 
> &= f\left( x_n \right) - f^\prime\left( c \right) \left( x_n - x_{n+1} \right) \\
> & \geq f\left( x_n \right) - f^\prime\left( x_n \right) \left( x_n - x_{n+1} \right) \\
> & \qquad \mbox{[ as $x_{n+1} < c < x_n$ and as $f^\prime$ is monotonically increasing, } \\
> & \qquad \mbox{ so $f^\prime \left( x_{n+1} \right) \leq f^\prime\left( c \right) \leq f^\prime \left( x_n \right)$.]} \\
> &= f^\prime\left( x_n \right) \left[ \frac{ f\left( x_n \right) }{ f^\prime\left( x_n \right) } - x_n + x_{n+1}  \right] \\
> &= f^\prime\left( x_n \right) \left( -x_{n+1} + x_{n+1} \right) \\
> &= 0 \\
> &= f \left( \xi \right);
> \end{align}
> $$ 
>   that is,  $f \left( x_{n+1} \right) \geq f \left(\xi \right)$, which implies that $x_{n+1} \geq \xi$, because $f$ is strictly increasing. If $x_{n+1} = \xi$, then, as above, $x_m = \xi$ for all $m \geq n+1$, and so $x_m \to \xi$ as $m \to \infty$. So we suppose that $x_{n+1} > \xi$, and proceed.
>
> Thus, for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, we have $x_n > x_{n+1} \geq \xi$. That is, the sequence $\left\{ x_n \right\}$ is monotonically decreasing and bounded from below by $\xi$; so this sequence converges, with $\lim x_n \geq \xi$.
>
> Put $$\eta \colon= \lim_{n \to \infty} \xi_n.$$
>   Then $\eta \geq \xi$.
>
> Now as $f$ and $f^\prime$ are differentiable on $[a, b]$, so these two functions are also continuous on $[a, b]$, which implies that both of 
>   the sequences $\left\{ f \left( x_n \right) \right\}$ and $\left\{ f^\prime \left( x_n \right) \right\}$ are convergent, with 
>   $$ \lim_{n \to \infty} f \left( x_n \right) = f\left( \eta \right), \qquad \lim_{n \to \infty} f^\prime \left( x_n \right) = f^\prime \left( \eta \right),$$
>   and, for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, as 
>   $$ x_{n+1} = x_n - \frac{ f\left( x_n \right) }{ f^\prime \left( x_n \right) },$$
>   so upon taking the limit on both sides as $n \to \infty$, we have the equation 
>   $$ \eta = \eta - \frac{ f(\eta) }{ f^\prime ( \eta ) },$$
>   which implies that 
>   $$ \frac{ f(\eta) }{ f^\prime ( \eta ) } = 0,$$
>   which in turn implies that 
>   $$ f(\eta) = 0,$$
>   and so $\eta = \xi$. 
>   Thus $x_n \to \xi$ as $n \to \infty$, as required.

Part (c):

> By Taylor's theorem we can find a point $t_n \in \left( \xi, x_n \right)$ such that 
>   $$ 0 = f\left( \xi \right) = f \left( x_n \right) + f^\prime \left( x_n \right)
> \left( \xi - x_n \right) + \frac{ f^{\prime\prime} \left( t_n \right) }{ 2 }
> \left( \xi - x_n \right)^2,$$
>   which implies that 
>   $$\frac{ f \left( x_n \right) }{ f^\prime \left( x_n \right) } + 
> \xi - x_n + \frac{ f^{\prime\prime} \left( t_n \right) }{ 2 f^\prime \left( x_n \right) }
> \left( \xi - x_n \right)^2 = 0,$$
>   that is, 
>   $$ \xi - x_{n+1} + \frac{ f^{\prime\prime} \left( t_n \right) }{ 2 f^\prime \left( x_n \right) }
> \left( \xi - x_n \right)^2 = 0,$$
>   and so 
>   $$  x_{n+1} - \xi =  \frac{ f^{\prime\prime} \left( t_n \right) }{ 2 f^\prime \left( x_n \right) }
> \left( x_n - \xi  \right)^2,$$
>   as required.

Part (d):

> Using what is given about $f^\prime$ and $f^{\prime\prime}$ and using what we have shown in Parts (a) and (c), we obtain
>   $$ 0 \leq x_{n+1} - \xi = \frac{ f^{\prime\prime} \left( t_n \right) }{ 2 f^\prime \left( x_n \right) }
> \left( x_n - \xi  \right)^2 \leq \frac{ M }{ 2\delta } 
> \left( x_n - \xi  \right)^2 = A \left( x_n - \xi  \right)^2  \tag{1} $$
>   for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$. So 
>   $$  0 \leq x_2 - \xi \leq A 
> \left( x_1 - \xi  \right)^2 = { 1 \over A } \left[ A \left( x_1 - \xi  \right)\right]^2 = { 1 \over A } \left[ A \left( x_1 - \xi  \right)\right]^{2^1}.$$ 
>   Suppose the required result holds for $k = 1, \ldots, n$, where $n \geq 1$. Then from (1) we see that 
>   $$ 0 \leq x_{n+2} - \xi \leq A \left( x_{n+1} - \xi  \right)^2 \leq A \left[ { 1 \over A } \left[ A \left( x_1 - \xi \right) \right]^{2^n} \right]^2 = { 1 \over A } \left[ A \left( x_1 - \xi \right) \right]^{2^{n+1}}.   $$
>   So by induction, the required inequality holds for all natural numbers $n$.

Here are the links to my posts here on Math SE on Probs. 16 and 18, Chap. 3, in Baby Rudin, 3rd edition:

[Prob. 16, Chap. 3 in Baby Rudin: $x_{n+1} = (x_n + \alpha/x_n)/2$, with $x_1 > \sqrt{\alpha}$, $\alpha > 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2291466/prob-16-chap-3-in-baby-rudin-x-n1-x-n-alpha-x-n-2-with-x-1)

[Prob. 18, Chap. 3 in Baby Rudin: Behaviour of $x_{n+1}=\frac{p-1}{p} x_n+\frac{\alpha}{p} x_n^{1-p}$ with $\alpha>0$ and $p$ a positive integer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2079222/prob-18-chap-3-in-baby-rudin-behaviour-of-x-n1-fracp-1p-x-n-frac)

Now Prob. 18, is when we put $f(x) = x^p - \alpha$, but what are our $a$ and $b$ so that all the conditions given above are satisfied by $f$ and its first and second derivatives? Of course, Prob. 16 is the special case of Prob. 18 when $p = 2$.

Part (e):

> As $f(\xi) = 0$, so $$ g(\xi) = \xi - \frac{ f(\xi) }{ f^\prime(\xi) } = \xi.$$
>   Thus $\xi$ is a fixed point of $g$.
>
> Conversely, if $x \in [a, b]$ is a fixed point of $g$, then 
>   $g(x) = x$; that is, 
>   $$ x - \frac{ f(x) }{ f^\prime(x) } = x,$$
>   which implies that $f(x) = 0$ and so $x = \xi$.
>
> Now 
>   $$ g^\prime(x) = 1 - \frac{ f^\prime(x) f^\prime(x) - f(x) f^{\prime\prime}(x) }{ \left[ f^\prime(x) \right]^2 }
> = \frac{ f(x) f^{\prime\prime}(x)}{  \left[ f^\prime(x) \right]^2 }$$
>   so that $g^\prime(x) \to 0$ as $x \to \xi$.
>
> Thus by taking $a$ and $b$ sufficiently close to $\xi$, we can make $\left| g^\prime \right| \leq { 1 \over 2 }$, 
>   and then we can apply the recursion $x_1 \in (\xi, b)$ arbitrary, and 
>   $$ x_{n+1} = g \left( x_n \right)$$
>   to converge to the fixed point of $g$, as has been established in Prob. 22 (c), Chap. 3, in Baby Rudin.

Here is the link to a post of mine here on Math SE on Prob. 22, Chap. 3, in Baby Rudin, 3rd edition.

[Prob. 22, Chap. 5 in Baby Rudin: Fixed Points of Real Functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2290165/prob-22-chap-5-in-baby-rudin-fixed-points-of-real-functions)

Part (f):

> For $f(x) = x^{1/3}$, we have $\xi = 0$.
>
> But $f^\prime(x) = {1\over 3} x^{-2/3}$ provided $x \neq 0$, 
>   while $f^\prime(0)$ does not exist; 
>   moreover $f^\prime(x) \to \infty$ as $x \to 0$, 
>   and $f^\prime(x) \to 0$ as $x \to \pm \infty$.
>
> And, for $x \neq 0$, we have $$ f^{\prime\prime}(x) = - {2 \over 9} x^{-5/3}.$$
>   So $f^{\prime\prime}(x) \to +\infty$ as $x \to 0-$, 
>   $f^{\prime\prime}(x) \to -\infty$ as $x \to 0+$, and 
>   $f^{\prime\prime}(x) \to 0$ as $x \to \pm \infty$.
>
> And, the Newton method recursion formula becomes 
>   $$ x_{n+1} = x_n - \frac{ x_n^{1/3} }{ {1 \over 3} x_n^{-2/3} } = x_n - 3 x_n = -2 x_n.$$
>   Thus, for arbitrary $x_1$, we have 
>   $x_2 = -2 x_1$, $x_3 = -2x_2 = (-2)^2 x_1$, and so on 
>   $$x_n = (-2)^{n-1} x_1.$$
>
> Thus, if $x_1 \neq 0$, then $$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \sup x_n = +\infty, \qquad 
> \lim_{n\to\infty} \inf x_n = -\infty.$$

Are all the parts of my solution correct and as required by Rudin? If not, then where have I erred?

Comment: With $e\in (a,b)$ and $f(e)=0,$ in case you ask how, when applying this practically, we can choose $x_1\in (e,b]$ without knowing what $e$ is, observe that we can take $x_1$ to be any $x\in (a,b]$ such that  $f(x)>0. $. For example in practice we can choose $x_1=b.$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet indeed!!